# Negation of uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose $f_{n}$ is a sequence of functions which does not convergence uniformly to $f$. Does this mean that there exists an $\varepsilon_{0} > 0$, an $x_{0}$, and a sequence of integers $n_{k} \rightarrow \infty$ such that $|f_{n_{k}}(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})| \geq \varepsilon_{0}$?

Comment: The point is not constant. So for each $k$ you might have a different $x$.

Comment: Literally what it means is that for any $\varepsilon>0$ and any $N$, there exists an $n_0>N$ and a point $x_0$ such that $|f_{n_0}(x_0)-f(x_0)|>\varepsilon$. Is that equivalent to what you said?

Answer (score 27):

If you know how to negate logical formulas with quantifiers, you can do this more or less mechanically.

Definition of [uniform convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) can be written like this:
$$(\forall \varepsilon>0) (\exists n_0) (\forall x\in S) (\forall n>n_0) (|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon) $$
Negation of uniform convergence
$$(\exists \varepsilon>0) (\forall n_0) (\exists x\in S) (\exists n>n_0) (|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge\varepsilon) $$

[Pointwise convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence) is defined as follows
$$(\forall \varepsilon>0) (\forall x\in S) (\exists n_0) (\forall n>n_0) (|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon) $$
negation
$$(\exists \varepsilon>0) (\exists x\in S) (\forall n_0) (\exists n>n_0) (|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge\varepsilon)$$
If you look closely at the negation of pointwise convergence, it is equivalent to condition from your question. Indeed, we have existence of $\varepsilon>0$ and existence of a point, which we many denote $x_0$, such that $|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|\ge\varepsilon$ happens for infinitely many $n$'s.
So any function which converges pointwise but not uniformly is a counterexample to the claim in your post.

Comment: Is it that, for some $\epsilon$ doesn't matter what $N$ you choose, there exist some $N_0 \geq N$  such that distance between $d(f_n(x),f(x)) \geq \epsilon ,\forall n>N_0$ ? Or there is no need of this, we can straightaway say there are infinitely many such $n$ ?

Comment: @MDesmond This seems a bit different question from the original post - I left a [short response in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/130704/2021/12/17).

Comment: In the definition of uniform convergence, shouldn't there be an implication somewhere, i.e. an $\implies$?

Comment: @sunny Saying $(\forall n>n_0)P(n)$ is the same as saying $(\forall n) (n>n_0 \implies P(n)$.